# CentOS5 python wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32

Tags: centos, python, 32bit-64bit

Has anybody ever encountered this wrong ELF class error?  The failure is provided in more detail below:

```
[root@nocloud ~]# system-config-users
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/system-config-users/system-config-users.py", line 25, in ?
    import libuser
ImportError: /usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/libusermodule.so: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32
```

Can anybody tell me how I might possibly be able to fix this?  It looks like python broke on my server.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like python is using libuser.i386 instead of libuser.x86_64. The error basically means python expected a 64-bit library but instead got a 32-bit library.

First, try installing libuser.x86_64, and try again ("yum install libuser.x86_64"). If that doesn't work, you may need to remove libuser.i386 and reinstall system-config-users.

Answer (score 0):

I have figured out the solution to this.  One can simply remove the file /usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/libusermodule.so and then the OS will automatically use the correct one located here: /usr/lib64/python2.4/site-packages/libusermodule.so